# How to set em to 10px for complete website

Tags: html, css, font-size

I am creating a template for responsive website. I learned that em is good to use in responsive design.

But problem is that I set the body font-size to 62.5% but when I am using p,span and other elements font-size like 2em than 2 em is different from 20px. according to my default font-size it should be 2em=20px anywhere in the body as 62.5% overrides default 1em=16px to 10px.

Please suggest what I should change so that in whole body whenever I set font-size of any element to 2em then it would be same a 20px.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
BODY {font-size:62.5%}
```

This takes 16px down to 10px. From now on it’s easy to think in pixels but still set sizes in terms of ems: 1em is 10px, 0.8em is 8px, 1.6em is 16px, etc.

```
.element {  
    font-size: 20px;  
    width: 4em;  
    height: 4em;  
}
```

Then that means that the width and height of the element (defined here as 4em x 4em) would compute to 80px x 80px (20px * 4 = 80px).

[Read 1](http://www.impressivewebs.com/understanding-em-units-css/)
[Read 2](http://clagnut.com/blog/348/)

Comment: i resolved the issue font-size=2em=20px i don't know but done But when i am taking margin in em is different from px like 2em!=20px.

Comment: you can get detailed explanation http://www.impressivewebs.com/understanding-em-units-css/

Comment: both links given by you are awesome i got the complete idea about em's before dis i was like completely mashed about em's thanks.

Comment: actually i tried to upvote your answer but i am anable to do so i don't know how to accept ur answer

Comment: Click the checkmark under this post, on the left. Also upvote it. (I think it's right below the arrows).

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Use [`rem`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#rem-unit) instead. It refers to the font size of the root element.

Comment: why i can't use rems. i Us it

Answer (score 0):

It might be the issue that your font size inherits from any parent tag...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The `em` unit equals, by definition, the font size of the element or, for `font-size` setting alone, the font size of the parent element.

The conclusions depend on what you really want to do, which is not clear from the question. If you want specific sizes in pixels, using the `px` unit (with all its [vagueness](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths)). If you want adjustable sizing, so that you or the user can easily change the basic font size and have all other font sizes scaled accordingly, use consistently the `em` unit or the `%` unit, with due consideration of element nesting. For example, use `font-size: 2em` only when you want the font size to be 2 times the size of the parent element’s font size—using a different value if you want a a different ratio.